# Docker Error "Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error, with Gitlab

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, gitlab

Ever time I run the pipeline the same issue presist in the system logs

```
> Gitlab-runner: {"driver":"amazonec2","level":"error","msg":"Error
> creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command
> error:","name":"runner-mw2q2exm-runner
> -1675768889-0d92c591","operation":"create",
```

could anyone help me with is why this error is comming , any help would be appricated

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue since this morning. There is a certificate copy error.
We upgraded docker-machine from v0.16.2-gitlab.15 to v0.16.2-gitlab.19 and it solved the issue.

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You saved my bacon, thanks.